# Video Streaming Using and conversion

Tags: javascript, video, streaming

I am getting data from a drone camera in a format like

```
<b32ded4a 01000000 708de749 01000000 fa6a1102 01000000 e0e7e549 01000000 f0675d6f 01000000 c051db01 01000000 b23d1b8e  3a050000 00000000 30ea44c4  01000000 00000000 00000000 306b5d6f 01000000  0000>
```

Can someone help me how to convert it into image data:video/webm;base64 format. It is actually a live video streaming.
So that using canvas i can change the image as data keeps coming. I am using socket.io for fetching data.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this might not be the answer but i cannot yet post comments everywhere. Please edit your question so i can see what you wrote after "like" in the first line.

Up in front here some resources how to encode webm;base64:

[Encode] http://antimatter15.com/wp/2012/08/whammy-a-real-time-javascript-webm-encoder/

[Binary to Base64]  [HTML5: Play video from stored binary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251136/html5-play-video-from-stored-binary-string)